# How do I add dynamically generated arrays with jq?

Tags: json, jq

I'm using jq 1.6 on Windows 7 and want to add a dynamically generated array to a json file.
That array doesn't yet exist in this file.

I've got the following JSON structure (reduced for reasons of clarity):

```
{
  "policies": {
    "SearchBar": "separate",
    "SearchEngines": {
      "PreventInstalls": false
    }
  }
}
```

I'd like to generate an array based on dynamic values and finally create the following output:

```
{
  "policies": {
    "SearchBar": "separate",
    "SearchEngines": {
      "PreventInstalls": false,
      "Remove": [
        "Twitter",
        "Wikipedia (en)"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The Remove array's content is stored in a (cmd) %variable%.
I found that the line

```
jq -n --arg items "%variable%" "{ Remove: $items | split(\",\") }"
```

produces the array I want:

```
{
  "Remove": [
    "Twitter",
    "Wikipedia (en)"
  ]
}
```

What is the best way to insert this array into the original file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the string input string `Twitter,Wikipedia (en)`, you can use jq to update the JSON data:

```
<file jq --arg i 'Twitter,Wikipedia (en)' '.policies.SearchEngines += ({ Remove: $i | split(",") })'
{
  "policies": {
    "SearchBar": "separate",
    "SearchEngines": {
      "PreventInstalls": false,
      "Remove": [
        "Twitter",
        "Wikipedia (en)"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah, the combination of `<file...` and the `+=` assignment I couldn't think of. Now it works like a charm, thanks!